# How can i use if/then/else in this context?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am having problem using the `if/then/else` statements.

here is my context:

```
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
$order = trim($_POST['order']);
$tel = trim($_POST['tel']);
$comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
$op ="0000-0000-0000";
$om ="mail@mail.com";
$bronze = "180 EGP/yr";
$silver ="280 EGP/yr";
$gold ="350 EGP/yr";
$plat ="420 EGP/yr";
$free ="EGP/yr";


if ($order == 'bronze') {
    echo "Please notice that your order will cost $bronze";
}
```

Now how can I do it again with `$silver` ? And so on like for `silver`, `gold`, `plat` and `free` or even if I wanna add more.

Comment: just give out seperate `if` conditions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [switch statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) would actually be a better fit for this situation:

```
<?php
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
$order = trim($_POST['order']);
$tel = trim($_POST['tel']);
$comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
$op ="0000-0000-0000";
$om ="mail@mail.com";
$bronze = "180 EGP/yr";
$silver ="280 EGP/yr";
$gold ="350 EGP/yr";
$plat ="420 EGP/yr";
$free ="EGP/yr";


switch ($order) {
  case  'bronze':
    echo "Please notice that your order will cost $bronze";
    break;
  case  'silver':
    echo "Please notice that your order will cost $silver";
    break;
  case  'gold':
    echo "Please notice that your order will cost $gold";
    break;
  case  'plat':
    echo "Please notice that your order will cost $plat";
    break;
  case  'free':
    echo "Please notice that your order will cost $free";
    break;
  default:
    echo "Please choose a service package.";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, **but** I'd like to point out that some of the other answers that suggested refactoring to use an array to store the cost information instead are much better solutions.  I would _urge_ you to try taking that approach instead!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`switch ... case`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) structure.

But if you have to do quite simple things, you can even refactor a lot using **associative arrays**.

Example:

```
$minerals = array(
  'gold' => array(
    'color' => 'yellow',
    'cost' => 350
  ),
  'silver' => array(
    'color' => 'gray',
    'cost' => 280
  )
);

// check order type
if (!isset($minerals[$order]))
  die("Unsupported mineral type ".$order.".");

echo "Please notice that your order will cost "
  . $minerals[$order]['cost'] . " EGP/yr.";
```

Comment: +1 for teaching not one but TWO better ways to do it. Although adding the actuall answer would have been nice, so you would have teached THREE new things in a single message!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look into the [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), this will allow you to perform different actions based on the value of `$order`.

Comment: so as like :
if ($order == bronze) {
    echo "bronze";
} elseif ($order == silver) {
    echo "i equals silver";
}
?

Comment: @IskonoMorto Yes, like that. Check my answer.

Comment: @IskonoMorto if/elseif will certainly work, but using a switch/case is usually more simple and readable in situations like this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if($order == "bronze")
{
   echo "Please notice that your order will cost $bronze";
}
else if($order == "silver")
{
   echo "Please notice that your order will cost $silver";
}
...
?>
```

The most easiest [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20else%20if&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aunofficial&client=firefox-nightly) would've brought you [this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).

Answer (score 1):

A very ugly way to do it would be like this:

```
echo 'Please notice that your order will cost '.$$order;
```

However, I don't recommend you doing it this way as it may cause lots of errors and security risk.

I would do it  with an array:

```
$plan = array(
    'bronze' => '180 EGP/yr',
    'silver' => '280 EGP/yr',
    'gold'   => '350 EGP/yr',
    'plat'   => '420 EGP/yr',
    'free'   => 'EGP/yr'
);

if(!array_has_key($order, $plan))){
    die('unknown plan');
}else{
    echo 'Please notice that your order will cost '.$plan[$order];
}
```

That way it's very easy to add new plans, even dynamically or from db.

Comment: Along with errors that first approach could also introduce security vulnerabilities. It could reveal other vars or could be used to echo out another user-provided var without sanitizing it.  Never output user provided data without first sanitizing it with something like [htmlentities()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).  Using an array for the prices on the other hand is an excellent way to handle this!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
if(!isset($$order)) {
    die("Invalid order type");
}

$cost = $$order;
echo "Please notice that your order will cost $cost";
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/2DT1g)**.

This will work correctly for any number of order types, without needing you to specify them again, and will also detect an invalid type.

**WARNING:** However, there is a security issue with this approach as Another Code correctly points out; a user could exploit this by crafting special values for `$order` that would cause your script to reveal the contents of any variable, which can be a pretty significant information leak.

**Preferably:** the same could be achieved in a more standard manner if you used an array for the order types, and this solution does not have any security issues:

```
$types = array(
    'bronze' => '180 EGP/yr',
    'silver' => '280 EGP/yr',
    // etc
);

if(!isset($types[$order])) {
    die("Invalid order type");
}

echo "The cost will be ".$types[$order];
```

Comment: Wouldn't be such a good idea for security if the value of `$order` comes from `$_POST`... this would allow a client to let the script echo the content of any variable.

Comment: a variable variable....i learned something new today !
but is it a good idea to use it ? it's kind of...confusing...

Comment: @AnotherCode: That's a valid point, which is another reason why the array-based solution I just finished adding is better. But mentioning variable variables also has an educational purpose, which is why I did so.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

```
if ( $gold == 'something' ) {
    echo "Please notice that your order will cost $bronze";
}

if ( $silver == 'something' ) {
    echo "Please notice that your order will cost $bronze";
}
```

Comment: thats what i mean :
if ( $gold == 'something' ) {
    echo "Please notice that your order will cost $bronze";
}

if ( $silver == 'something' ) {
    echo "Please notice that your order will cost $bronze";
}
but it shows the first result only

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
<?php
$key=0;
switch ($order) {
    case "bronze":
         $key=$bronze; 
          break;
    case "silver":
          $key=$silver;
           break;
    case "gold":
          $key=$gold;
          break;
    default:
         $key=1;
          break;
}

echo"Please notice your order will cost $key amount";
?>
```